# Why doesn't my video show an image before pressing play on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So there's no background image before playing a video on this website I made on mobile devices. This is the code I'm using in HTML

```
 <div class="row " >
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <video  controls>
            <source src="image3/video.mov" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="image3/video.mov" type="video/ogg">
          </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

This runs fine on my laptop it's just on my phone that shows no background image of the video before pressing play.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `poster` attribute on the `video` element.

From MDN:

> **poster**
>
> A URL for an image to be shown while the video is downloading.
> If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the
> first frame is available, then the first frame is shown as the poster
> frame.

```html
<video controls poster="https://www.ddfl.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bunnies-easter.png">
  <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/bfd_download/sample-mp4-file/"
            type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried adding a seperate image as the thumbnail?
Like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <video poster="placeholder.png" controls>
            <source src="image3/video.mov" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

**poster=""** sets an image as the starting frame (thumbnail), more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp).